# WiLINQ: TFS 2012

Tags: c#, linq, tfs

I'd like to use a LINQ to TFS Provider, and it seems like WiLINQ is the way to go.
The Problem: We have TFS 2013 on the Server and only VS 2010 and 2013 on the Development-Clients.
Since the WiLinq is only obtainable for TFS 2012, my questions:

- Is it still possible to work with it with the DataStructure of TFS
  2013?
- How Do I get the VS 2012 SDK (or the needed DLLs) to the local
  Computers to get the reference going?

Or would you say, on this Environment, there is no "right" way to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the 2012 API's available to be able to run a tool that depends on that version. There is a redistributable for the API's alone however on local workstations it can be easier to install Team Explorer.

- [TFS 2012 Update 4 Object Model](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa)